# How can I use the PayPal API with a Signature instead of a Certificate?

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to use the `signature` option instead of `certificate` and I don't see the option.

[image]

Where can I find the signature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. I had to revoke the certificate to get this to happen. You can apparently have one or the other.